# Is it possible to use tooltip with an image in map tag?

Tags: dictionary, tooltip, coordinates, area

I'm just wondering if it is possible to use tooltip with image inside area tags. I find it easier and lighter way to pop-up a short information about a specific location, with picture. The tooltip with image is working just fine but when I use it along with the coord it will be a text.

Here's the code I tried using

```
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="The Ampitheater<img src='images/wizard-v2-bg.jpg'/>">
            <area shape="circle" coords="636,604,81" href="#">
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to set a title to each area.

But the tooltips can't have an image in pure html.

Look at this snippet as example:

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm" title="sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm" title="mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm"  title="venus">
</map>
```

If you still want them to have an image you can do it with some libs like Jquery Tooltips. See an example here: https://codepen.io/jeprubio/pen/bGdGaam . In that case you need some extra javascript and css files (as you can see in the settings of the codepen).

**Update**

You can see the codepen example also here with all the code in a single html:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
img {
  margin: 10px;
}
.ui-tooltip {
    max-width: 350px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

  <map name="planetmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm" title="sun <img src='https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sun-icon-jpg-260nw-416254921.jpg' height='100'>">
    <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm" title="mercury <img src='https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/system/stellar_items/image_files/2_feature_1600x900_mercury.jpg' height='100'>">
    <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm"  title="venus <img src='https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/dzxtQ2dXH9SVKztJTbAXSA-320-80.jpg' height='100'>">
  </map>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
  <script>
    $( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      items: "[title]",
      content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "title" );
        }
      }
    });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference, however, when I tried copy and pasting your code on my computer its still in a text format.

Comment: What do you mean? Which one? The one of the codepen you need to add all the javascripts and css code (the ones that you see in the panes and the files which you can see in the settings).

Comment: I did. Is there a link I need to insert?

Comment: Something must be missing, I've added an update with the example of the codepen as an html code snippet. With all the css and javascript in there.

Comment: OMG it's working now! Thank you so much for the help!